# Не могу разобраться с Get запросом на Go

Tags: golang, rest

имеется запрос : `https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c840629\/v840629491\/204b7\/Oxt4HkuHVyU.jpg`

если передавать его в качестве параметра для функции `http.Get(https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c840629\/v840629491\/204b7\/Oxt4HkuHVyU.jpg)`
компилятор отдает ошибку из-за слешей. Как можно с этим бороться, и как корректно передать его в функцию. 
Пишу на Go.

Comment: 1. Прямые слеши вроде не надо экранировать (то есть как минимум вам стоит убрать все обратные слеши). 2. Также функция [`Get`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Get) принимает строку, соответственно стоит и передавать строку: `http.Get("https://...")`

Comment: Где вы нашли такой синтаксис вызова?

Comment: прощу меня простить, при написании вопроса совершил ошибку
правильный синтаксис вызова
http.Get("https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c840629\/v840629491\/204b7\/Oxt4HkuHVyU.jpg")

Comment: да ничего страшного) что насчёт убирания всех обратных слешей?

Comment: тогда запрос будет не верен, и. я не получу данные. 
То есть мне нужно оставить запрос таким, но при этом передать его в функцию.

Answer (score 1):

Надо сделать так:

```
http.Get("https://pp.userapi.com/c840629/v840629491/204b7/Oxt4HkuHVyU.jpg")
```